# Oracle CASE issue - after THEN NOT NULL

Tags: oracle, case, notnull

I edit Oracle Report when I need add input parameter for number column. I want use list of values for values:

- 0 - No
- <> 0 - Yes
- all = All

In my code runs correctly "No" and "All" but for "Yes" I do not know what to do.
Could you help me, please?

```
 AND column1 = (CASE 
                  WHEN (:p_parameter = 'YES') THEN <> 0
                  WHEN (:p_parameter= 'NO') THEN 0
                  WHEN (:p_parameter = 'ALL') THEN column1
                  ELSE column1 
              END)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure that value of p_parameter is in the correct cases that is YES not in lower case(like yes or Yes)??

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `case` in `where` clauses. Simple logic always does the trick

```
AND 
(
  (:p_parameter = 'YES' and column1 <> 0) OR
  (:p_parameter = 'NO' and column1 = 0) OR
  (:p_parameter = 'ALL')
)
```